# set sender address in postfix smtp relay

Tags: gmail, postfix-mta

I have setup postfix locally on my Linux box, it relays to my gmail account. This works nicely thanks to http://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_relaying_through_another_mailserver

However I would like to be able to specify the sender address (From:), I could not figure out what I needed to do. Does anyone knows how I can specify any of my (pre)configured valid gmail address ? All I could find is this:
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did post this question to the debian-users group and got the following answer:

> You can specify any headers with -a, e.g.
>
> $ mail -a 'From: "My Name" ' da

http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/04/msg00993.html

Which works beautifully